# how installing chained foreignkey

Tags: django

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user '91815'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-chained-foreignkey (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-chained-foreignkey